# Only one chain is appearing in Miner Status on Antminer S9

Tags: asic, error, antminer

I just hooked up my miner after returning from training. when i first hooked it up all 3 chains were visible but then i moved the miner to a more permanent location and hooked it back up. now only one chain is appearing. i thought it might have been an issue with the 110 outlets, so i unhooked one hash board so only one board is hooked up to my PS (i use 2, one for one board and the miner, the other for 2 boards). Even after doing this only one chain is appearing.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why you would be expecting to see more than one chain. The whole point of the blockchain is to achieve decentralized consensus on a single longest chain that is to be treated as the ground-truth. -- Am I missing some context from the mining lingo where chain is something else than elsewhere in Bitcoin?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a possibility one of your power-supplies have gone bad? You can further debug this by obtaining the "Kernel log" found on the "System" tab. I would also try re-seating the cables, and test each hashboard individually (power them one at a time to determine if they are still OK -- *make sure to shutdown/unplug your miner before performing any work*!)

If you can provide that file, more information should be available.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. First 1 board went down. Then a second board. I read that low temperatures (5 degrees Celsius or lower) will make the miner act this way. Unplug all power supply cords from the miner. Let the miner get back to a more reasonable room temperature. All my boards came back and showed under miner status.